# Перевод кода из Pascal на VB

Tags: pascal, vba, vb.net

Нужна помощь в переводе с Pascal на VB (VBA)! Не получается перевод массива!
Pascal:

```
Procedure obuch;
  begin
 repeat
 clrscr;kol:=kol+1;
 writeln('****************************************************');
 writeln('*   Эталон    * Значение на выходе *  Отклонение  *');
 writeln('****************************************************');
   For i:=1 to N_obuch do begin
     y:=0;
    For j:=1 to n do y:=y+w[j]*x[i+(j-1)];
     y:=y-t;
    For j:=1 to n do begin
       w[j]:=w[j]-alfa*(y-x[i+n])*x[i+(j-1)];
       t:=t+alfa*(y-x[i+n]);
       err:=err+sqr(y-x[i+n]);
             end;
 writeln('*  ',x[i+n]:10:7,'  *     ',y:10:7,'     * ', abs(y-x[i+n]):10:7,'   *');
       end;
 err:=err/2;
 writeln('****************************************************');
 writeln;
 writeln('Ошибка :  ',err:8:5);
 read;
 until (err <= Ej);
  end;
```

мой перевод (несовсем правильный) на VB:

```
Function obuchenie()
Const a = 3, b = 5, d = 0.5, alfa = 0.1, n = 4, Errj = 0.01, N_obuch = 30
Dim i, j, kol As Integer
Dim err, y, t, rmp, zn As Long
Dim W(n) As Long
Dim X(45) As Long
Dim x_prgnz(45) As Long
kol = kol + 1
Print     "*******************************************************"
Print "************"
Print "********************************************************"
Do
For i = 1 To N_obuch
y = 0
For j = 1 To n
y = y + W(j) * X(i + (j - 1))
y = y - t
Next j
For j = 1 To n
W(j) = W(j) - alfa * (y - X(i + n)) * X(i + (j - 1))
t = t + alfa * (y - X(i + n))
err = err + Sqr(y - X(i + n))
Print "********"; X(i + n); "********"; y; "********"; Abs(y - X(i + n)); "********"
Next j
err = err / 2
Print "****************************************************************"
Print "Ошибка:"; err
Next i
Loop Until (err <= Errj)
End Function
```

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что этот сайт — не бюро переводов

Comment: Я бы так радикольно не поступал..Название функции показывает,что человек учится и старается понять, есть попытка написания. Не обязательно делать полный перенос кода. Подсказать, направить...

Answer (score 1):

В VB не шарю, но сразу сходу:

1. В исходном тексте на паскале не хватает секции с объявлением переменных.
2. После `For j:=1 to n do y:=y+w[j]*x[i+(j-1)];` делается `y:=y-t;` один раз. У Вас `y = y - t` попало в цикл по `j`.
3. `Print "********"; X(i + n); "********"; y; "********"; Abs(y - X(i + n)); "********"` должно быть после `Next j`.
4. `Next i` должно быть сразу после пункта 3.

Как-то так. Внимательнее читайте код. А лучше, отформатируйте его так, чтобы четко было видно где начинаются и заканчиваются циклы. И тогда сразу сами увидите все ошибки.

Comment: На паскале эта процедура работает отлично....внимательно посмотрите, что это процедура!

Comment: Может она и работает отлично, но в том коде, что вы здесь написали нет объявления переменных. Либо это процедура вложена в другую процедуру и используются ее переменные, либо используются глобальные переменные. В любом случае, все они должны быть где-то объявлены.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub obuch()
  Do
    Cls: kol = kol + 1
    Print "****************************************************"
    Print "*   Эталон    * Значение на выходе *  Отклонение  *"
    Print "****************************************************"
    For i = 1 to N_obuch
      y = 0
      For j = 1 to n: y = y + w(j) * x(i + j - 1): Next
      y = y - t
      For j = 1 to n
        w(j) = w(j) - alfa * (y - x(i + n) * x(i + j - 1)
        t = t + alfa * (y - x(i + n))
        err = err + (y - x(i + n)) ^ 2
      Next
      Print "*  ", x(i + n), "  *     ", y, "     * ", abs(y - x(i + n)), "   *"
    Next
    err = err / 2 '' (надо уточнять - возможно имелось в виду err \ 2)
    Print "****************************************************"
    Print
    Print "Ошибка :  ", err
    system "pause > null"
  Loop Until err <= Ej
End Sub
```

переводил буквально (без анализа действий программы), в текущем виде подходит для исполнения на каком-нибудь qbasic. для vba нужно заменить Print на Debug.Print, system - на что-нибудь еще (можно просто удалить - все равно ничего не делает).

PS: от форматирования выводимых чисел я тоже отказался - на память не помню.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim i, j, kol As Integer
```

Нужно переводить как:

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, kol As integer
```

Это особенность VBA, тип каждой переменной объявляется отдельно, иначе `kol` будет иметь тип `Integer`, а `i, j` - `Variant`.

Answer (score 0):

В VBA нужно объявлять все переменные и явно присваивать им типы (тип прописывать каждой переменной). Не обязательно, и без объявления будет работать, но для объявления есть несколько причин.

1. Экономия оперативной памяти. Если тип не указан, переменная будет `Variant`, а этот тип откусывает наибольший куск памяти.
2. Поиск ошибок. Всегда в начале модуля (над всеми процедурами) должен стоять оператор `Option Explicit`. Он помогает отследить необъявленные переменные и многие ошибки в коде (не закрыт оператор, в переменную пытаются передать не тот тип данных, кириллица вместо латиницы (как отличить `С1` от `C1`?) и проч.
3. Культура написания кода.

Зачем объявлены переменные, которые в функции не используются?

`kol = kol + 1` - зачем лишняя операция? Переменная - тип целое, по умолчанию  равна нулю. Достаточно `kol =  1`.

Но это попутные ошибки, которые не приводят к неработоспособности кода.

`Print` - А здесь ошибка. В `VBA` нет такого.  `Debug.Print`- результат выводится в окно `Immediate` - для отладки, контроля параметров... `MsgBox` - сообщение.

`Dim X(45)` - задана размерность массива. Нумерация элементов - с 0 до 45 (46 элементов). Это тоже надо учитывать. По Вашему коду видно, что на первых шагах циклов заполняются элементы с индексом 1, нулевые как бы лишние:

```
W(j) * X(i + (j - 1))... ==> W(1) * X(1 + (1 - 1))... ==> W(1) * X(1)...
```

Но главное, чего нет в Вашем коде - функция не возвращает значение. Возможно, для решения этой задачи нужна не функция, а процедура - `Sub/End Sub`.

Функция в `VBA` вызывается откуда-то (из процедуры, из другой функции, из формулы листа), в нее передаются параметры (не всегда) и она после отработки должна вернуть обратно результат обработки.

Пример:

```
Sub test()
    Dim dSum As Double
    Dim a As Double, b As Long

    a = 22.4: b = 70
    ' вызываем функцию, передаем параметры, в dSum получаем ответ'
    dSum = fResultSum(a, b)
    MsgBox dSum, 64, "Ур-р-а!"
End Sub

Function fResultSum(s1 As Double, s2 As Long, Optional n As Byte = 5) As Double
    Dim k As Double

    k = s1 - s2 + n
    If k < 0 Then k = Abs(k)
    fResultSum = k ' функция получает результат'
End Function
```